# How to Adding a properties to a incoming response data?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

initPayment giving me response data,which is actually came from a payment gateway.So i need to add a properties to this response data.So that i can get this properties with the response data. How can i do that?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    initPayment(userInfo.token)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.status === "SUCCESS") {
          setSessionSuccess(true);
          setRedirectUrl(response.data.GatewayPageURL);
          setFailed(false);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setFailed(true);
        setSessionSuccess(false);
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [userInfo.token]);
```

Comment: Can you not just add a property to `response`, i.e. `response.newProperty = "some new value"`? What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: I have tried this,but not working. @DrewReese

Comment: Can you share your response object and what you want to add to it?

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do and provide clear details about what isn't working?

Comment: this is my response object
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    //others code
}
I wanna add a object to this like 
{ name: "demo",
age:20
} @Ammar

Comment: Did you try doing this inside `if` condition?
`const newData = { ...response.data, obj: {  name: "demo", age:20 } }`